# How to change size of textboxfor in view MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change the size of TextBoxFor with new htmlAttributes but its not working any other solution?

```
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Serial_No, htmlAttributes: new { @style= "size:10" })

    </td>
```

Comment: Whats not working?  What does this render in HTML?

Comment: You just need to do this `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Serial_No, htmlAttributes: new { size: 10 })`

Comment: `new { size = "10" }` (`style= "size:10"` is not valid)

Comment: What you mean by size ? How big(wide) the textbox is ? How many characters it can contain (maxlength) ?

Comment: i just wanna decrease textbox width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Serial_No, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "yourCustomClass" } })
```

and then in css file

```
yourCustomClass{
height: 60px;
min-width:400px;
etc;
}
```

and if by size you mean maximum number of characters then

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Serial_No,  new { maxlength="10" });
```

Comment: thats awesome but i want to decrease width of textbox not its length of characters

Comment: then in the css file --> max-width: 100px;

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out which css attributes to use to specify the size of the textbox. Consider height: "xxxpx", font-size: "yyypx" to start with.

In general, it is helpful to use the Chrome debugger (F12) to inspect the generated element and work out what html is going to answer your problem. You can then translate that back into the correct style htmlAttribute.

Answer (score -1):

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Serial_No, new { style= "width:10px" })

Comment: I'm using this syntax now and it works fine for me. Is there something wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: Having inline css, in general, is not a good practice. I believe you don't need the @ there either.

Comment: the @ is not mandatory. i agree. its only needed for c# keywords. the inline thing though, isn't that what the op was doing? Anyway removed the @

Comment: Well that was just my guess on the reason you have been down voted. though even I don't see anything wrong with your answer